# How do I set background color of Line Series chart in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Line Series Chart in Flex with values from 0 to 90. I would like to set the background of the chart in such a way that, 0 - 30 is in green, 31 - 60 is in red and 61 - 90 is in blue.

I am new to Flex. Can someone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: This image should give a better idea of what I am trying to acheive: http://www.e-ness.fr/images_html/pikonet_test4.png

Answer (score 2):

This is super old, but I stumbled upon it while Googling and for posterity sake, wanted to add this.

The best and preferred way is to set the backgroundElements property of the chart. Here's an example:

```
<fx:Array id="backgroundChartElements">
<mx:GridLines>
    <mx:horizontalFill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="1" />
    </mx:horizontalFill>
    <mx:horizontalAlternateFill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha=".5" />
    </mx:horizontalAlternateFill>
</mx:GridLines>
</fx:Array>
<mx:LineChart backgroundElements="{backgroundChartElements}" ... />
```

See [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c45.html) document for more information on messing with the background and grid lines

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called `CartesianDataCanvas` that is designed for this kind of thing.

You add an instance to the chart's `backgroundElements` and use a drawing API to draw on it.  What is handy is that the drawing API on these objects works in terms of data coordinates, not screen coordinates saving you a lot of converstion work and making scaling and resizing much easier.

More [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this would be to set the graphs maximum and minimum to fixed values(so that it doesn't auto re-size) and draw the color bars behind it using the normal drawing api.